# Are there any canonical references of the political aspects of sustainable living?

Tags: defining-sustainability

I think that there is a clear and close interplay between politics and sustainable living. What I mean by this is that I think that sustainable ways of living should be reinforced politically to spread them among the society. In some cases the relation between the two [is very clear](https://sweden.se/nature/sustainable-living/).

I've been trying to find some books or articles about this topic but I've had some difficulties so far. I've come across concepts like [ecosocialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainability#Ecosocialist_approach), social sustainability, micro-sustainability, ...

The quantity of information is overwhelming and I'm a bit lost right now. So, is there any canonical reference in this topic? A classical book (or set of notes, paper, ...) about the relation between politics and sustainable living?

Comment: Is there a particular location you're interested in - I think the answer might depend on the place and the size, whether it's a village in India, or the whole European Union.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I'm specially interested in the European Union or Spain, but I don't care about the size.

Comment: @A.A. although sustainable living should definitely be reinforced by all political powers, it should be above them all. Like some general obligation which has to be administered by any party on power. People tend to move away from certain political parties (for example in Central and Eastern Europe the left and extreme left parties talk a lot about environmental topics, but barely anyone would vote the extreme left party). If the topic gets isolated to only a few parties, then we risk having it on the losing side.

Answer (score 1):

Dessler and Parson, [The Science and Politics of Global Climate Change: A Guide to the Debate](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0521519241) (2009, 190p) on climate ?  (Sustainability is an even larger topic.)  Don't know about "canonical", but [MacKay](http://withouthotair.com/) says "helpful further reading".

Minogue, [Politics: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0192853880) (1995, 118 p)
is not about sustainability at all, but is 2 σ thought and writing:

> The nicest thing to do with a hard choice is to evade it.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a literature on alternative economic models, e.g.

- Green Economics: An Introduction to Theory, Policy and Practice. Moly
  Scott Cato,  ISBN-13: 978-1844075713
- Supply Shock: Economic Growth at the Crossroads and the Steady State
  Solution. Czech, B. 2013. and other works on [steady state
  economics](https://steadystate.org/discover/reading-list/)
- This Changes Everything: Capitalism vs. The Climate. Naomi Klein.

There are also books on society's response (or lack of it), for example:

- Don't Even Think About It: Why Our Brains Are Wired to Ignore Climate Change. George Marshall (Bloomsbury US, 2014).